# Add a string after each item in Wordpress sub menu

Tags: menus

I am trying to add a special character to display a » alongside each menu item in Wordpress.

So for example

About us »
Contact us »
And so on...

Here's my code

```
      <li><?php echo $children; echo '»'; ?></li>
```

I expected this would do the job, but it just puts the » below the list.

Here's the full code

```
      <?php
      if($post->post_parent) {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
      $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
      }

      else {
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
      $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->ID);
      }
      if ($children) { ?>

      <h2 class="left_title">
        <?php echo $titlenamer ?>
      </h2>
      <ul class="left_body">

        <li><?php echo $children; echo '»'; ?></li>

      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in three ways:

1) Use before and after arguments in [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

2) Write a custom walker

3) Use CSS :*before* or :*after* pseudo classes to add the character. The character must be in [escaped unicode](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%C2%BB), e.g.:

```
li:after {
 content: '\00BB';
 padding-right: 5px;
}
```

There is more in a similar [StackExchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717957/can-i-add-a-separator-li-after-the-anchor-tag-in-wordpress-wp-nav-menu)